# Import sql into php and i want to add a new line after the data. How?

Tags: php, sql, grid, dhtmlx

So i have a dhtmlxgrid in php, that full filled  by an sql from a Firebird odbc. Firstly i cant handle the heights of the rows.
Seconly i think about that its enough to me that if i put a new line into every cell, and i found it that its easier that if i concatenate with the datas from sql then  do it after .
I tried every version of `concat(), concat_ws(), +, ||` etc...
I also use `'\n'`.

I have an index.php which just load the grid. In this only here can do sg about this:
`

```
<?php

$xml = 'connector.php';
echo '

<div id="gridbox"   ></div>
<script>
    doOnLoad("gridbox","'.$xml.'","0")
    {   gridbox.enableAutoHeight(true);
        gridbox.enableAutoWidth(true);
        gridbox.setAwaitedRowHeight(250);

};
</script>
';



?>
```

`
This calls the connector.php which load the datas and create the rows like:

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rows >
 <head>
     <column  width="150"       type="ro"           align="left"  sort="str"                   >xy</column > 

     <afterInit> 
        <call command="attachHeader">
                <param>#text_filter,</param>
         </call>


    </afterInit> 
 </head>
</rows>');
```

And the sql which write the datas is:

```
$sql = "
    select  distinct
    supexport.partner,
from supexport
where

";
```

And this part of code is write the datas into the rows:

```
while ($row = $db_supexport->ReturnRow()) {
    $currSor = $xml->addChild('row');
    $currSor->addChild('cell',$row[0]);

}
```

(I cut the codes just to siplify it :) )

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes `"` for special characters with `\` to have an effect. Also, concatenation in php is done with a period sign `.`.

```
$string . "\n";
```

Comment: Nope, it is not work:
<php    sql="select  distinct
    supexport.partner."\n", 
from.....
where...";
;>

Comment: maybe "\r\n" (CrLf newline)

Comment: Nope, another tips?

Comment: Edited the quetion :)